# Pantheios and Logger Hierarchy

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx, pantheios

I'm taking a look at a few logging libraries for my software.  I've noticed that a lot of people recommend it and that it boasts some pretty good performance statistics.

I know that the website claims that Pantheios can act as the top level layer and you can define custom front ends and backends to plug in any other logging library.  What I'm most interested in is the Logger Hierarchy concept for log4cxx.

I would like to be able to log in a hierarchical manner across my components so that I can set different log levels for different components.  however with Pantheios I'm unclear on how to do this?

I understand that I would have to override their stock backend and frontend with my own for log4cxx.  But how do I tie Pantheios into different log4cxx loggers?  Do I need to define a backend per logger for this to work?

Would appreciate the communities insight on this one.